# What does "буде будет" mean?

Tags: словоупотребление, выражения, particles, conditional

Browsing the Internet, I saw the following sentence in a text:

> (1) То, что **буде будет** считаться стильным и модным, какой принт стоит выбрать и как все это сочетать в нашем сегодняшнем фотогиде. ([Source](https://just-interes.ru/news/%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1-9-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85))

Puzzled by the construction **буде будет**, I performed a Google search and found numerous examples of its use:

> (2) В будущем он **буде будет** анализировать психологические процессы в группах космонавтов во время длительных миссий, а также изучать их реакцию на присутствие роботов. ([Source](https://apparat.cc/news/mcs-flying-brain))
>
> (3) Зимний интерьер, **буде он будет** выдержан именно в этом стиле, сдержанном и простом, чистом и в некотором роде напоминающим бумажный лист, позволяет создавать особенное настроение – уравновешенное, спокойное. ([Source](http://spektrsec.ru/zima-i-skandinaviya-idealnyiy-interernyiy-kokteyl.html))
>
> (4) И не понимал того, что свобода, **буде она будет** дана, будет прежде всего использована всеми для обмана всех. ([Source](https://mybook.ru/author/dmitrij-bykov/saltykov-shedrin-2/citations))
>
> (5) Практически гулять скоро **буде будет** негде, - говорит одна из подруг. ([Source](http://ecopress.center/page3149217.html))
>
> (6) Некий абстрактный "Закон российский", даже **буде он будет** принят, во-первых "исполнять не обязательно", а во-вторых уважать уже тоже не принято, потому что любой новый закон неспроста воспринимается как закручивание гаек и попытка ободрать народ. ([Source](http://fisher.spb.ru/blogs/view.php?postId=1555))
>
> (7) Генпрокуратура назначила на должность прокурора Анжеро-Судженска Константина Шевяко. Он **буде будет** исполнять свои обязанности пять лет. ([Source](https://www.kem.kp.ru/online/news/3119287))

Intrigued, I looked for explanations and found a grammar [source](https://www.journals.uio.no/index.php/osla/article/download/230/280) that says the following:

> На территории Архангельской области есть два «разорванных» ареала особенно интенсивного употребления *буде*: северо-западный (север Онежского и Приморский р-ны), где *буде* играет роль союзного средства в сравнительном
> обороте, и южный (Каргопольский, Вельский, Вилегодский, Котласский, Красноборский, Устьянский р-ны), где *буде* функционирует как союз в условно-гипотетических конструкциях и как модальная частица эпистемического характера.

Concerning the use of **буде** as *модальная частица эпистемического характера*, the source clarifies:

> *Буде* сообщает высказыванию семантику приблизительности в оценке количества ... неуверенного предположения относительно ситуации настоящего или прошлого ...

The source also gives various examples like "слишком богомольных у нас буде нету."

In view of this source, I guess that in Examples (3), (4), (6) **буде** is *союз в условно-гипотетических конструкциях*, whilst in Examples (1)-(2), (5), (7) - *модальная частица эпистемического характера*, but I am unsure about the precise meanings of **буде будет** in those sentences. My humble guess is that roughly speaking, these meanings are close to **if**  [in Examples (3), (4), (6)] and **will probably** [in Examples (1)-(2), (5), (7)].

I understand that **буде** is a somewhat archaic and/or dialect word, but it is still extensively used in the modern Russian language as shown by Examples (1)-(7), even in newspapers such as *Комсомольская правда*, which is where I took Example (7) from, so I want to understand this word in order to properly interpret it in texts and be able to show off by using it.

My question is this: How do you understand **буде будет** in general and in Examples (1)-(7) in particular?

Comment: seem like typos, erroneous reduplication, Internet is good but Russian national corpus is more reliable, if you find such sequences there, we'll have to have some discussion

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка I highly doubt. I saw numerous examples of such use, and I also found old texts with the same expression.

Comment: how numerous? as an error a few dozens or even hundreds is permissible i guess

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Do you really think there can be such typos in *Комсомольская правда*?

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка I saw such phrases even in writings of classic Russian writes, when I performed by Google search. I will now try to show some examples.

Comment: why not Комсомольская правда, they aren't infallible, are they? OK, let's see

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Dostoevsky, a classic Russian writer, wrote, "**Буде будет** когда-нибудь времечко, что-нибудь черкните Вашему наипреданнейшему Федору Достоевскому," This was at the end of his letter to Aksakov. Link: https://www.rulit.me/books/pisma-1880-read-170587-28.html

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка >>why not Комсомольская правда, they aren't infallible, are they?<< In each newspaper there are editors and correctors, so each text there is checked by many people, so I really cannot imagine that such a typo could be made in a serious newspaper.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка I found in Google another example of the use of **буде** in an old text: там бы мне положить, зделав мояк, правианту в бочках небольшее число, по моему разсуждению, причем **буде** было и рыбы сухой для корму собак, понеже де ему Лаптеву востребует [ся] и нужда, ежели он пойдет сухим путем, а ежели же де бог благоволит ему морем проити, то де по тому ж тот правиант им Лаптевым от того места возметца на судно. This is from a letter of Minin, dated 1740, link: http://91.144.189.235/fulltext/Bering.pdf

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка I also found some examples in the Russian National Corpus: "**буде будет** желание Ян Цзин-гэна, дать ему отставку," "**буде будет** челобитье от гражданина других чинов на людей, то за президента быть от юстицкого суда."

Comment: OK, so the meanings i believe are as Ainar-G suggested, but it's archaic and whenever it occurs in a modern text, i mean within about last 100 years at least, where it doesn't aim at stylisation of sorts, then it is likely to be a typo, and all the more so in recent texts, because it's obsolete

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка In which of the examples given in my post the word **буде** is a typo, in your opinion?

Comment: 1,2,5,7 are typos.

Comment: agree with @tum_, i admit to being too rash in my judgement

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Сегодня какой-то "буде-день": на форуме вдруг попался [пост](https://glav.su/forum/2/540/messages/5276030/#message5276030), где человек это *буде* в смысле *если* аж два раза употребил :) Это просто индивидуальная особенность, некоторые любят "пощеголять" словечками типа "оные", "ея" или там "оне" (иногда употребляя их неправильно). If overused it becomes both ridiculous and annoying. Вопрос вкуса, в общем.

Comment: @tum_ right, there was a spell when some people were overdriving with дабы or ибо

Comment: @tum_ thanks a lot. I see in the Russian National Corpus that you are right - the word **буде** is used there exclusively as a substitute of **если**, so 1,2,5,7 must be typos.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка it takes a lot of bravery to admit own mistakes. By the way, I am still curious about two things about **буде**. First, does **буде** imply the future? It seems **буде** originated from **будет**. Or is it okay to use **буде** for conditions on some past situation? Like, *буде он не нарушал закон, ему нечего бояться*. Is it okay?

Comment: Second, given that **буде** seems to have originated from **будет**, isn't **буде будет** a repetition from the logical standpoint? The thing is that I saw phrases like **будет у него работа - тогда он сможет заработать деньги**. Apparently the word **будет** does there exactly what **буде** does - the very same thing. Now adding **буде** to the beginning of that sentence would be an illogical repetition, or wouldn't it?

Comment: Or are these things worth asking a separate question on this forum?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93803/discussion-on-question-by-mitsuko-what-does---mean).

Comment: @Mitsuko i feel that it sounds more idiomatic in future conditioning, but my perception is affected by modern language, so to know for sure i think National corpus should be consulted, and i agree with your observation regarding the tautology, so it seems that for the sake of style the use of **буде** in conjunction specifically with the verb **будет** is best avoided, but again patterns of its actual use can be gleaned from the Corpus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Half of them is an archaic form of “если”: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5. Example from Wiktionary:

> Буде помещик возьмёт земледельца в дом свой для услуг или работы, то земледелец становится свободен.

The other half are clearly typos.

Comment: What can you then say about the sentence "слишком богомольных у нас **буде** нету"? The sentence is from an official grammar source affiliated with the Moscow State University (see the link in my post). How is **буде** equal to **если** in that sentence?!!

Comment: I think that in the MSU's sentence it is actually a synonym to “поди”. That is, “слишком богомольных у нас _поди_ нету”. Can't say without a broader context.

Comment: >>I think that in the MSU's sentence it is actually a synonym to “поди”<< Why then **буде будет** cannot be interpreted as **поди будет**? It makes perfect sense in the examples I provided. Он **буде будет** исполнять свои обязанности пять лет - Он **поди будет** исполнять свои обязанности пять лет. Doesn't it make sense?

Comment: Because words like “поди” are not typically used in formal speech. To say nothing about an archaic form of it. Reading something like that in a newspaper would be really odd. Re. Комсомольская Правда. The link you've given is for Kemerovo's regional КП, which probably has less better proofreading. And besides, I've seen worse misprints in federal news agencys' articles (although those tend to be corrected within a day).

Comment: >>Because words like “поди” are not typically used in formal speech. To say nothing about an archaic form of it. Reading something like that in a newspaper would be really odd.<< How is it if just found the word **поди** in an article title(!) in *Комсомольская правда*: "**Поди** пойми этих женщин: сначала пугают маму, что выйдут замуж, потом пугают мужа, что уйдут к маме..." Link: https://www.kp.ru/daily/26393/3270970/ And if **поди** is used in *Комсомольская правда*, why **буде** can't?!!

Comment: A couple of more example of **поди** in *Комсомольская правда*: (a)  А ведь он **поди** и не такие слова знал (https://www.smol.kp.ru/daily/25683/888762), (b)  Другой вопрос: сколько в фильме осталось от Конана Дойла? Ну, так он, **поди**, стерпит, глядишь, не перевернется… (https://www.kem.kp.ru/daily/25816.4/2794676).

Comment: I see in the Russian National Corpus that you are right - the word **буде** is used there exclusively as a substitute of **если**, so 1,2,5,7 must be typos. So your answer must be correct, and I mark your answer as an accepted answer.